# Address of a dereferenced InputIterator? The case of istream_iterator

Tags: c++, dereference, istream-iterator

I have a legacy code in which the interface is defined for pointer. 
I am trying to adapt some functions to take iterators, e.g. forward iterators.

**Is one allowed to take the address of the element dereferenced by InputIterator such as `istream_iterator`?**

The result is a temporary and has to be is somewhere in memory for the life of the call, but I am not sure.

The following example uses `double`, but the type can be more complicated (large).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<sstream>

void f_legacy(double const* t){
    std::cout << *t << std::endl;
};

void f(std::istream_iterator<double> it){
    f_legacy(std::addressof(*it)); // OK????
    // to avoid a copy:     auto v = *it; f_legacy(std::addressof(v));
}

int main(){
    double d = 5.;
    std::istringstream iss("1 2 3");
    std::istream_iterator<double> it(iss);
    f_legacy(&d);
    f(it);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always legal to take the address of an lvalue.

Since `istream_iterator::operator*` returns a reference, it must be returning a reference to an object that survives beyond the function call, and until the iterator is advanced. So your code is well-defined.

Comment: Although true for `istream_iterator`, in the general case there is no guarantee that dereferencing an InputIterator returns an lvalue.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: 27.2.3 in the C++ spec requires that operator* for an InputIterator returns a reference, so this should be fine for any InputIterator, not just istream_iterator.  A simple Iterator is not required to return a reference, however.

Comment: @ChrisDodd No, it specifies that it must return `std::iterator_traits<X>::reference`, but that type is not required to actually be a reference. Such a requirement is imposed starting with the forward iterator category.

Comment: @Brian: per 27.4.1, iterator_traits::reference must be a reference type except for output interators

Comment: @Brian, I just checked GCC STL and `operator*` return `const _Tp&` which means that `::reference` is not used for that. Not sure if this is ok with the standard. Reading the implementation, it is also that this function returns `_M_value` which means that the iterator is storing the actual value somewhere (probably until `operator++` is called again)

Comment: @ChrisDodd Are you looking at a version where 27.4.1 is [iterator.traits]? I don't see any mention of `reference` being a reference type.  It does say "the iterator's reference type" is the same as the type of `*a`, but I think that phrase is just meant to describe `iterator_traits<Iter>::reference`, and not to imply that it must be a reference type.

Comment: @alfC I clearly said that Brian's answer is true **for `istream_iterator`**, why are you asking me if it doesn't have to be an lvalue? I also said it's not true in general for other kinds of InputIterator. Not all InputIterators are the same as `istream_iterator`. Looking at the implementation of `istream_iterator` only tells you about `istream_iterator`, not other kinds of input iterator.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, the forward iterator requirements include that `reference` is either `T&` or `const T&` but that's not required for input iterators. The requirement for the `reference` type of an input iterator is only that it's convertible to `T` (the value type). It does not have to be `T&` or any other kind of lvalue.

Comment: Since `istream_iterator` seems to be special case, I could optimize the function for such iterator. In fact I can automatically optimize the copy if it is not necessary, I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287221/optimize-inputiterator-dereference-without-making-a-copy-if-possible?noredirect=1&lq=1