# Optimize InputIterator dereference without making a copy if possible?

Tags: c++, dereference, object-lifetime, istream-iterator, const-reference

I have a legacy code in which the interface is defined for pointer only and I am trying to adapt some functions to take iterators.

In the answers to this question [Address of a dereferenced InputIterator? The case of istream_iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267066/address-of-a-dereferenced-inputiterator/49267131?noredirect=1#comment85539731_49267131)
it was noted that `std::istream_iterators` are `InputIterator`. 
However they are special among `InputIterator`s, because their dereference is guarantied to generate a language reference `T const&`.

The code for a general input iterator would look like this, notice that I have to generate a copy of the value type to take the address.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<sstream>

void f_legacy(double const* t){
    std::cout << *t << std::endl;
};

template<class InputIt>
void f_aux(InputIt it, std::input_iterator_tag){
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;
    value_type v = *it; // creates a local copy, *might be* unnecessary
    f_legacy(std::addressof(v));
}

template<class It>
void f(It it){
    f_aux(it, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category{});
}
int main(){
    double d = 5.;
    std::istringstream iss("1 2 3");
    std::istream_iterator<double> it(iss);
    f_legacy(&d);
    f(it);
}
```

However for `std::istream_iterator` this is not optimal because an unnecessary copy is made. (I don't know if it can be optimized, but that is another question.)
So I could add an overload to handle the optimizations for `istream_iterator`.

```
void f(std::istream_iterator<double> it){
    f_legacy(std::addressof(*it));
}
```

or more verbose

```
void f(std::istream_iterator<double> it){
    double const& v = *it; // no copy is made
    f_legacy(std::addressof(v));
}
```

**The question is, can I just use this following version of `f` *without* writing an overload of `istream_iterator`?**

```
template<class InputIt>
void f_aux(InputIt it, std::input_iterator_tag){
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;
    value_type const& v = *it; // a "copy" is made only if necessary
    f_legacy(std::addressof(v));
}
```

I think this should work due to https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ , but I am not sure if it applies.

or even this one liner:

```
template<class InputIt>
void f_aux(InputIt it, std::input_iterator_tag){
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;
    f_legacy(std::addressof(static_cast<value_type const&>(*it)));
}
```

Note: In the real code all the functions are templated, `double` is just a placeholder here.

Comment: The one liner should work: [static.cast](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#4). If `*it` is a `pr-value` a temporary is materialized to hold the value, this temporary will last until the end of the full expression. if `*it` is an l-value the result of the static_cast will be a reference directly bound to `*it`.

Comment: @Oliv, thanks, I think it would work only because of the `const&` in the static cast.

Comment: Indeed a `&` without the const would not have work: [dlc.init.ref](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.ref#5.2)